# Svelte-Electron: Error occurred when executing command: yarn run dev

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, svelte

I use template from https://github.com/soulehshaikh99/create-svelte-electron-app , and it works just fine for a while. Been normally developing for days, but when I restart my computer/vs code, the command `npm run electron-dev` (concurrently "yarn run dev" "yarn run electron") suddenly not working.

The error messages are:

```bash
[0] Error occurred when executing command: yarn run dev
[0] Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
[0]     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
[0]     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
[0]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[1] Error occurred when executing command: yarn run electron
[1] Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
[1]     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
[1]     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
[1]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[1] yarn run electron exited with code -4058
[0] yarn run dev exited with code -4058
```

I tried to reinstall with yarn/npm, there are some error dependencies, but I was able to resolve them. Yet, the error above still occurred.

What is this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the system can't find the `cmd.exe` for some reason.

first, try restarting your computer, sometimes it is the solution for this type of error.

if that didn't work check the variable path for your `cmd.exe`, normally should point at `C:\Windows\system32`, so if it is not pointing at the `cmd.exe` you will have to find it and change the variable to point at it.

Comment: I've read in another topic, that I should add the path variable with `C:\Windows\System32\` . Or `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` ?

Comment: yeah, the `C:\Windows\system32` is the correct one I just checked it on my PC.
i will edit the answer, let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: It work! notes: after changing the system variable, it's not working directly, so I have to restart my computer, and now it's all working. Thanks